# gradle, gretty - How to run a task in farm task?

Tags: gradle, gretty

I would like to run a task in `farm` task:

```
farm {
   // run my task here.
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you be please more precise about what you need to do? As far as I see _farm_ is an _extension_ and tasks are not designed to be run inside extensions.

Comment: I would like to call ./gradlew farmRun , and it will automatically run one of my task or function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then define a dependency between your task and `farmRun` task.

Comment: Dear Opal, can you show me exactly the way, I have no clue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`farm` is an extension - not a task - so it cannot be run. Also mind the fact that it's not good idea, nor good practice to run task programmatically. You need to define your own task and then define a dependency:

```
task myTask << {
   println "Here's an action"
}

farmRun.dependsOn myTask
```

or:

```
task myTask << {
   println "Here's an action"
}

project.afterEvaluate {
   farmRun.dependsOn myTask
}
```

Please have a look at the demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/35594778).

Comment: Hi, I got error with farmRun.dependsOn  Could not find property 'farmRun' on project ':bl-notification-server'. and replace it to farm.dependsOn myTask, after that another error occurs: A problem occurred evaluating project ':bl-notification-server'.
> Could not find method dependsOn() for arguments [task ':bl-notification-server:myTask']. Please advise, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Opal, it's no error now when I run: ./gradlew farmRun, but I cannot see the line:  Here's an action.

Comment: @LeKimTrang, added the demo to prove that it works well.

Comment: Dear Opal, thank you very much. It's really help. How's about gradle deamon? Can we treat gradle deamon as task? Thank you very much.